# trouble with location regex and redirection in nginx

Tags: nginx, regex

I want to setup proxy in nginx:

```
location ~ ^/m/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/redir/m/$1/$2/$3;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

It works but this address

```
http:// myhost/m/test//ss
```

gets translated to

```
http:// 127.0.0.1:8080/redir/m/test/ss;
```

How can I get my second slash?? 
Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  A `//` is defined as being equivalent to `/`, and nginx will always reduce a URL to the canonical form before passing it on.